# Yii2 routing: url-rule not working when the "/index"-action is not explicitly specified

Tags: yii, routes, yii2

This route need a little extra work in order for it to work properly, but I am not able to see what I need to do:

```
'http://<caregiverName:\w+>.' . $domain . '/<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
```

When I make call like this **controller/action**, everything works fine. When I make this call **controller** (without the explicit index) in order to make call to actionIndex, I am not able to catch **caregiverName** param. But when I make this call **controller/index** (index explicitly specified), it works normally.

What I need to rework in the router?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things:

#### Rule for calls without `index`

You need a second rule with the index as a static value when it is not provided. Add this **after** your first rule like so:

```
'http://<caregiverName:[\w-.]+>.' . $domain . '/<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
'http://<caregiverName:[\w-.]+>.' . $domain . '/<controller:\w+>' => '<controller>/index',
```

The reason for this is that yii will to this normally, but not for your explicitly defined rule. The reason to put it after is that it would otherwise match before the other and always put you on the index page ;-).

#### Regex corrections for domain-characters

In you rule you use `\w+` as a placeholder for a domain name. the way you specified your rule, it won't work with any other characters than "word-characters" (`a-zA-Z0-9_`). The dot (subdomain) and the dash (-) are missing! For the domain `perfectly.valid-subdomain.com` your rule won't work. You can find an axplanation of the regex shorthands [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html).

Check out my example above how I specified the character classes. You could of course also validate the length etc, but this is not the scope of this answer...you should get the gist.

Tell me if you need more information!